# C# Outlook interop and OpenSharedItem for opening MSG files

Tags: c#, interop, outlook, office-interop, msg

Is there any tutorial or resource I can follow in order to use the OpenSharedItem outlook interop method. My goal is to read MSG files using it (as it can [apparently](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._namespace.openshareditem.aspx) do so).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[How to: Create a Contact Item from a vCard file and Save the Item in a Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb646856.aspx)

[How to: Import Saved Items using OpenSharedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176433.aspx)

Answer (score 25):

Thanks Svetlozar, I've used the resources to create something like the following:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

var item = app.Session.OpenSharedItem("C:\\test.msg") as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem;
string body = item.HTMLBody;
int att = item.Attachments.Count;
```

It may be useful to others looking for a quickstart as I was.

Comment: Also possibly useful to others: Remember to call Marshal.ReleaseCOMObject(item); once you're done with item; this will ensure the file does not remain locked by Outlook.