# Problem with reading *.msg outlook file using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, msg

I'm writing piece of code which will handle extraction of information from email stored in *msg Outlook file. The idea how to do it I took from [C# Outlook interop and OpenSharedItem for opening MSG files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907045/c-outlook-interop-and-openshareditem-for-opening-msg-files). But when calling method OpenSharedItem a get such error `System.AccessViolationException`. Anyone know what's the problem?
Here is code causing error

```
Outlook._Application app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace NS = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFld = NS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
Outlook.MailItem fld =  (Outlook.MailItem) app.Session.OpenSharedItem("E://Projects//C#//message1.msg");
```

Comment: I think this can be due to version of Outlook. Somewhere I found that it works only since Outlook 2007. Anyone can confirm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok. In case anybody will face the same problem finally I've got an answer. First of all  should be

```
Outlook.MailItem fld =  (Outlook.MailItem) app.Session.OpenSharedItem("E:\\Projects\\C#\\message1.msg");
```

difference is in the slashes.
Then all you need to make it work is Outlook 2007 or newer. And that's it :]