# Create MailMessage object from .msg File Path?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

Is there a way to create a MailMessage object from a directory path of a .msg file?

Such as MailMessage x = new MailMessage("path")

Comment: Do you mean create a MIME (EML) file from an Outlook's MSG file?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct conversion between these two entities out of the box - the Outlook message file and the `MailMessage` class from the .net framework. You can automate Outlook to get the instance of the MSG file instantiated using the [NameSpace.OpenSharedItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.openshareditem) method which is used to open iCalendar appointment (.ics) files, vCard (.vcf) files, and Outlook message (.msg) files.

You can also use Redemption for that, look for `RDOSession.GetMessageFromMsgFile`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies but I found the answer on this existing post: [C# Outlook interop and OpenSharedItem for opening MSG files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907045/c-sharp-outlook-interop-and-openshareditem-for-opening-msg-files)

Like Eugene said, I used the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application to open the .msg file via Outlook.